# How to update only specific layers from Tensorflow Lite model into Android app?

Tags: python, android, firebase, tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I have a custom `tensorflow.keras.models.Model` CNN model with layers from `tensorflow.keras.layers` that I aim to deploy in an **Android app**, using Tensorflow Lite.

I am currently converting this model from a saved one (folder containing a .pb file, an assets folder and variables folder - created from `my_model.save(path_save)`) by using the [Python API](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/convert/python_api) :

```
import tensorflow as tf

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model('./my_model')
tflite_model = converter.convert()
with tf.io.gfile.GFile('my_model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
  f.write(tflite_model)
```

I then download this TFLite model on my app using [Firebase and its ML Kit](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ml-kit/android/use-custom-models).

However, I'd like to make regular updates of this model (**changes that would concern only a few layers**) without having to download it all (which is what I'm doing as of now) : this is a waste of ressources, as my model is quite heavy and most of the layers will not be changed at all.

**Is there a way to do it ?** Ideally it would just receive a file describing the layers to be changed.

Comment: The only thing that I am aware of is that you can resize input size to dynamic range models inside android. so do you refer to something like that? Do you refer to input only?

Comment: No the input is not supposed to change, but some of the hidden layers are

Comment: Unfortunately, TFLite does not support this right now. Feel free to file an issue on github and mention that this is a "feature request" along with details about your use case. (If the problem is not about the conversion to TFLite, but about downloading the new model into the application using Firebase, you ignore this comment)